# How to declare scope in Rails paths?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, scope, rails-routing

I have an article resource that's defined as a flat resource, but also as one scoped to a variable user:

```
resources :articles
scope ':user' do
  resources :articles
end
```

In this case, `article_path 123` will generate `/articles/123`. How can I generate a scoped path, e.g. `/mary/articles/123`? For example, `article_path 123, user: 'mary'` doesn't work; it just adds `?user=mary`.

`rails routes` shows there's no special name for the scoped path:

```
article_path    GET /articles/:id(.:format) articles#show
                ...
                GET /:user/articles(.:format) articles#index
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding, `as` to create route helpers

```
scope ':user', as: 'user' do
  resources :articles
end
```

You will get

```
user_articles_path(user, article)
```

Check also [routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#prefixing-the-named-route-helpers)